# Updating an array using a function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a very nooby problem.

```
void update(node city, int costpath) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < city.concity.size(); i++) {
        city.costcity[i] = city.costcity[i] + costpath;
    }
    // Updates the sorrounding paths with the cost path of the previous one
}
```

`node` is a `struct`. It has vectors `concity` and `costcity`. When I call this function to update the values in the main, it doesn't work! When I print it out, it still shows the same old values…

Comment: Pass in a pointer to `city` instead, you're just operating on a copy.

Comment: Please indent your code with four extra spaces.  Also, avoid tabs.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more formatting help.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

```
void update(node city, int costpath) {
//          ^^^^ 1) You're taking your node by-value. So it's a copy
//                  Internal to this function, you're just modifying the local city
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<city.concity.size();i++) {
//       ^^^ 2) C++ is zero-indexed, so this loop skips the first element
```

The correct implementation would be:

```
void update(node& city, int costpath) {
    for (int i = 0; i < city.concity.size(); ++i) {
        city.costcity[i] += costpath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I noticed the one and changed it..... The second part work wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ pass parameter by value when call function.

```
void update(node* city, int costpath) {
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<city->concity.size();i++) {
    city->costcity[i] = city->costcity[i] + costpath;
    }
}
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value

and http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms:Pass_by_value

Answer (score 0):

pass `node city` as a pointer or reference to the function.
c++ is `0` indexed thus start with `0` and increment till the array size.

```
void update(node& city, int costpath) {
```

or

```
void update(node* city, int costpath) {
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < city.concity.size(); ++i) {
```